# How to Update OpenSSL version from OpenSSL 1.0.1t to OpenSSL to 1.1.1u

Tags: docker, openssl, dockerfile

I am using **Docker (version 18.05.0-ce)** for building and deploying of node service.

I am not specifying OpenSSL anywhere through out my service.

Not sure how OpenSSL is getting installed in the docker container.

The current version of OpenSSL is **1.0.1t**. I wanted to change it to **1.1.1u**

What changes do I need to make in my Dockerfile ?

Below is the Dockerfile that I am using.

```
FROM node

ARG ENVIRONMENT
ARG PORT

ENV PORT $PORT
ENV ENVIRONMENT $ENVIRONMENT

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -my wget gnupg

RUN mkdir /deamon_service
ADD . /deamon_service
WORKDIR /deamon_service

RUN npm cache verify
RUN npm install

EXPOSE $PORT

ENTRYPOINT [ "node",  "server.js" ]
CMD [ $PORT, $ENVIRONMENT ]
```

Any help will be appreciable